# How to append to a global list?

Tags: python, python-2.x

```
candidates = [2,3,5]
candidates.sort()
target = 8
ans = []
temp = []
start = 0

def backtracking(temp,candidates,remaining,start):
    global ans
    if remaining < 0:
        return
    elif remaining == 0:
        if temp not in ans:
            ans.append(temp)
        print ans,"ans"
    else:
        i = start
        print i,"st"
        while i < len(candidates):
            temp.append(candidates[i])
            print i,"i"
            backtracking(temp,candidates,remaining-candidates[i],i)
            temp.pop(len(temp) - 1)
            i += 1


backtracking(temp,candidates,target,start)
print ans
```

So when I try to print my list `ans`, I get `[[]]` — I am not able to append the `temp` list to the global list `ans`. How does one do that?

Comment: `.append()` appends a single element (which can be a list itself).  Maybe you want to use `.extend()` instead (or maybe `+=`)?

Comment: What would the correct value be for `ans`?

Comment: correct ans would be [[2,2,2,2],[2,3,3],[3,5]]

Answer (score 0):

You cannot append a list like that in Python. You can append like `list = list1 + list2`. So in place of `ans.append(temp)` you need to write `ans = ans + temp`.

Comment: Actually what i want is a structure that will append a list within a list, like [[],[]], something like this.

Comment: Then you can do `ans += [temp]`

Comment: Yes, because this is a recursive situation, if you trace you will see that local variable `temp` is popping the values and inserting the unseen ones and you cannot match them with this `if temp not in ans:` condition. So the temp is getting empty and in the last scenario you are appending an emplty `temp` list to `ans` thus getting `[[]]`. But in case of value appending the `if` condition ensures new value to append in global variable `ans` and it doesn't pop anything so you get `[2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 5]`

Answer (score 0):

Using `ans.append(temp[:])` instead of `ans.append(temp)` works.
But I don't know why yet.